# Rational integral conjecture of $(x^{2k} - \sin(\pi x))^2$

Tags: definite-integrals, rational-numbers, trigonometric-integrals

I was messing around, and came up with the following conjecture:

$$\int_{-1}^1(x^{2k} - \sin(\pi x))^2dx = \frac{4k+3}{4k+1}$$

More generally, it seems that for any polynomial $P$ with rational coefficients we have that $\int_{-1}^1(P(x^2) - \sin(\pi x))^2dx$ is rational. Which leads me to ask three questions:

1. Is the conjecture correct?
2. Is the more general conjecture about the rationality of $\int_{-1}^1(P(x^2) - \sin(\pi x))^2dx$ correct?
3. If yes, is there a formula that given $P$ (e.g. as  a series of coefficients $a_k$) computes $\int_{-1}^1(P(x^2) - \sin(\pi x))^2dx$?

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for all $x$, then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx=0$.

Comment: in all cases, after expanding the square, the mixed term $P(x^2) \sin (\pi x)$ integrates to zero

Comment: also $ \sin^2 (\pi x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos (2 \pi x)  $

Comment: @blueInk I think the other hints are correct, but your explanation is not. Consider $P(x^3)$, your same argument applies yet it's _not_ rational in this integral.